# hvplot(geo=True) argument maps XY coordinates to incorrect latitude coordinates

Tags: python, panel, holoviews, hvplot, geoviews

I have a raster of the Northern beaches, Australia, in the UTM CRS projection for this region (56S). Now when I'm plotting this data using the `hvplot.xarray` extension as `da.hvplot(x="x", y="y", geo=True)`, the argument `geo=True` triggers y coordinates [meters] to be converted to coordinates [lon, lat], but the latitudes are mapped as northern hemisphere coordinates. They become `lat = 90 + (-y)`, whereas it should simply be `lat = -y`. Which function is triggered by `geo=True` that infers the coordinates from XY to lon/lat?

Plotting with matplotlib works fine, see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRC68.png

##### Aim

Overal objective is to overlay the vector data (shoreline) on top of the raster (ndwi).

##### Some software version

python==3.10.8

```py
hvplot.__version__  # '0.8.2'
holoviews.__version__  # 1.15.3
```

##### Complete, minimal, self-contained example code that reproduces the issue

```py
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import geopandas as gpd
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.tile_sources as gts
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.xarray
import xarray as xr

ndwi = xr.open_dataset(
    "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/floris.calkoen.open.data/narrabeen_ndwi_2023-01-24T00%3A02%3A21.tif",
    engine="rasterio",
)
shoreline = gpd.read_file(
    "https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/floris.calkoen.open.data/narrabeen_shoreline_2023-01-24T00%3A02%3A21.geojson"
)

ndwi.rio.crs == shoreline.crs  ## true

utm_zone = shoreline.crs.utm_zone
southern_hemisphere = True if utm_zone[-1] == "S" else False
utm_code = int(utm_zone[:-1])
utm_crs = ccrs.UTM(
    utm_code, southern_hemisphere
)  # why cartopy.crs.UTM() doesn't handle utm zone strings?

shoreline_plot = gv.Path([shoreline], crs=utm_crs)
ndwi_plot = ndwi["band_data"].squeeze().hvplot(x="x", y="y", geo=True, crs=utm_crs)

shoreline_plot * gts.EsriImagery  # this seems correct 

ndwi_plot # see how the XY coordinates are converted from XY UTM zone 56S to latitudes in the northern hemisphere (90 + (-y)) 

shoreline_plot * ndwi_plot  # therefore the overlay doesn't work

# to plot with matplotblib
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ndwi["band_data"].squeeze().plot(ax=ax)
shoreline.plot(ax=ax, color='black', linewidth=5, label="shoreline")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Holoviews isn’t working directly with the crs - it’s just depending on gdal to project the data, which is extremely widely used and isn’t likely the culprit. Are you sure you have the right CRS? Have you tried just plotting with matplotlib? I expect you’d see the same behavior.

Comment: @MichaelDelgado, thanks for your help. The crs of both objects are the same. And I can plot the data with matplotlib, see https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRC68.png. The unexpected behaviour starts when I add `geo=True` to `hvplot()`. Shall I open an issue on GH?

Comment: Sure - but if you do it would be better to develop a simpler MRE, created with code. You could create a very simple polygon using shapely directly. See this guide to [crafting a minimal bug report](//matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/02/28/minimal-bug-reports).

Comment: I would also include the code you use to plot in matplotlib which does work so the team can see whether/if there are any inconsistencies in the code

Comment: But also - I actually meant in matplotlib using a cartopy projection. I expect it is your projection definition which is not working, so the image you linked to doesn’t actually show the correct behavior in matplotlib - that’s just a direct plot of the (untransformed) x/y coordinates